# No volume and unconnected wires

Tags: electric-guitar, maintenance

I have a LTD ESP Snakebyte and the bridge volume knob is overturning and I think it took one of the wires out when I turned it too much. I checked the wires that go to the input and both of them are in the right spot. However theres a red wire that splits off into three different sections and it's not connected to anything.

Comment: Hi, and welcome! It would help if you could include some more information about your issue, and maybe a picture showing the problem. It's difficult to understand exactly what's wrong at the moment.

Comment: Do you know anything about electronics? Do you know how to solder and do you have a soldering iron? If the answer to any of these is “no”, your best option is to take it to a guitar tech or luthier to have it fixed.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with @ToddWilcox. I would suggest that you learn to solder and do it yourself, except the Snakebyte is an expensive model and damage is a risk. Good luck!

Comment: Given the limited information, Todd's comment is as good as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem I see come through the repair shop. The nut holding the pot loosens, allowing the pot to rotate out of position from where it was mounted which can break off the wires at the solder joint.

As Todd answered in the comments, unless you know how to solder and follow a wiring diagram, the best thing to do is to take the guitar to a technician and have the pot reconnected and tightened.

Answer (score 0):

Some pickups have wires that aren't used, except for certain applications. If the guitar was working prior to the Pot being banjo'd then the problem lies with the pot. change it out. they are inexpensive and easy to swap out.